# Ampersand in field while saved set &amp; then &amp;amp; until too large for update

Tags: fields, record

Sorry if there are already subjects about this, didn't found anything.

Here is my problem : some records contains "&" in fields (or accents). They have to. Those fields are automatically updated and used as mapping values, so I cannot really control them.

When record is saved, `"&"` become `"&amp;"`.

Then record is updated and value become `"&amp;amp;"`. Then `"&amp;amp;amp;"` and so on ...

Correct them manyally will just do the same.

It's causing me 2 problems :

1. my values get false (and this value is used for mapping)
2. at some point the value is getting too large and update fails.

Example : a record with `"Johns & Johns"`, automatically created. If a lead is created with "Johns & Johns", some apex code should value a lookup with this record.
But when I save it, value becomes `"Johns &amp; Johns"`. Then `"Johns &amp;amp; Johns"`.

Same thing with accents that are registered with html values `"&eacute;"` then `"&amp;eacute;"` and so on.

---

Edit 2019-11-15
Since it could be some trigger code, i searched and found this function, the only on used on those field

```
public static String specialCharHandler(String f){
    String str = f.escapeHtml4();
    system.debug('str::-->>' + str);
    str = str.replace('&nbsp;',' ');
    system.debug('str22::-->>' + str);
    return str;
}
```

---

Ok, i made some tests and this is the cause of the behavior.

Thanks cropredy for helping me understand the problem. Would have vote for your comment if it was an answer ;)

Comment: Can you add relevant apex trigger code?

Comment: something in your code is doing encoding when this is not required; SFDC text fields accept any valid UTF-8 character so extra encoding should not be required

Comment: Ok thanks guys. That's a start. I will check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the encoding in an old apex class called by an apex trigger.

```
code.escapeHtml4();
```

Just commented it.

Thanks cropredy.